# populating array at the beginning of the program

Tags: c++, arrays

Is there a way to populate the array at the beginning of the program? I need to populate an array with a 100 elements and all the elements should be zeros.

this is my array:

```
const int arraysize = 100;
int a[arraysize];
```

I know that I should use a `for` loop but I don't know where to put the `for` loop in the code. If i put it in the main it doesn't work either. Because a separate function is using the array. The array isn't being used in the main.

For Loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    a[i] = 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a[arraySize]{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) can be used to initialize an array. You can specify values for a whole array, the start of an array or none of the array. Any part that isn't specified is initialized to 0 or default constructed (depending on the type of array). Take a look at the following example.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const int arraysize = 10;
    int a[arraysize] = {1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 5, 5, 0, 2, 7};
    int b[arraysize] = {1, 2, 3};
    int c[arraysize] = {};


    for(int i = 0; i < arraysize; ++i) {
        std::cout << a[i] << ' ' << b[i] << ' ' << c[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output of the example.

```
1 1 0
2 2 0
3 3 0
6 0 0
8 0 0
5 0 0
5 0 0
0 0 0
2 0 0
7 0 0
```

Comment: Oh okay. I get it now. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why nobody mentioned `memset` yet.Yes i know that if you want to fill your whole integer array with 0 or -1,only then `memset` works.But the example you gave indicates that you want to fill your whole array with 0.That's why i am explaining `memset` to you.`memset` is a c function that comes with `#include<string.h>` or you can add it in c++ by `#include<cstring>`

### memset

This C library function **void *memset(void *arrName, int valueForAll,sizeof(arrName))** copies the value **valueForAll** to every element of the array pointed to, by the argument **arrName**.

### Example

The following example shows the usage of `memset()` function.

```
const int arraysize = 100;
int i,a[arraysize];
memset(a,0,sizeof(a)); /* fills the whole array with 0 */
memset(a,-1,sizeof(a)); /* fills the whole array with -1 */
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    printf("%d\n",a[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[arraysize] = { 0 };
```

See here:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization

> If T is array type, each element is zero-initialized

This only works for filling the array with zeroes.